# Relevance of selected activity in a fitness tracker while using a heart monitor

Tags: heart-rate-monitor

I work as a cycle courier so my shift involves cycling, climbing stairs and sometimes walking around while waiting for a job.

I'd like to record my activity with something like Strava or Endomondo but don't want to have to keep changing the activity.

If I'm using a chest strap heart monitor will the calorie burn be calculated solely from that? My understanding is that the selected activity is just for a) a record of what you did and b) to more accurately calculate calorie burn based on time/ speed whatever. It's this correct?

My plan was just to record the shift as 'other' or even 'ride' and be aware that's not all I did and the calorie burn would still be (as) accurate (as it can be).

Comment: I suggest you contact the manufacturer of your product. We don't know much about the inner workings of... well, we don't even know which product it is.

Comment: Thanks. That's a fair point, but as I said, my 'device' is an app on a phone (Android) and a chest strap heart monitor (BerryKing but does that make a difference?)